# Sending a http get request to a server with known public ip

Tags: python, ip, server

I have a server running by using python's base http server. The host name used is '127.0.0.1' the local host, and the port number is set to 8000. I have the public ip address of the computer operating this server.
If I wanted to send a http get request to this from another computer, what would I type into my browser?

Comment: Doesn't http://<public ip>:8080 work?

Comment: I tried, but it just loads forever on my side. And on the server's side there is nothing printed indicating reception of a request.

Comment: Make sure your server is listening on all interfaces and not just 127.0.0.1. The settings is usually either 0.0.0.0 or *.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got your server process running on the wrong interface.  127.0.0.1 is not a hostname but an *IP address*, specifically the local loopback address.  It is not reachable from any other machine (unless something's gone tragically wrong with your network configuration).

You can run anything you like on the 127.0.0.1 interface, and no one else can directly connect to it from a remote machine.  That's pretty much the point --- it's for testing programs that use the Internet Protocol, and (in recent years) for starting single-user servers without worrying about security.  (Python 2's [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) does this, as do some personal wikis, and I think iPython Notebook.)

The public address for the host running your Web server is a *completely unrelated* network interface, with its own hardware and its own port 8000.  It doesn't know or care that you've got something listening on some *other* interface's port 8000, so it should refuse attempts to connect to that port.

Since you didn't post any code, I have no idea what you need to change to get your server running on the correct interface.  Assuming you've more or less followed the [example in the `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html):

```
def run(
  server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
  handler_class=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler,
  ):
    server_address = ('', 8000)  # <----=  Replace the string.
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

That `server_address` tuple is a string containing the IP address (`'1.2.101.202'` or whatever), followed by an integer port number.  So **replace the string with your host machine's public-facing IP address**.

Note that port 8000 is outside the reserved range (0 up to but not including 1024), so it's possible that some unrelated service is already using that port.  ([Numerous applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) are already squatting port 8000.)  If so, you'll just have to choose another port number.  You can chose anything from 1024 up to but not including 65536, but as with 8000, someone else might already be using it.

Depending on your operating system and its security setup, you might not have permission to open a socket that listens on an arbitrary port number.  If so, that's between you and your ISP or sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

http://yourip:port/func

yourip is your public ip.
port is 8080

func is your registered function.

and also make sure you port is opened